# How to determine whether paper was dipped in acetone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds

I was wondering if there was a solution of some sort that would cause a reaction to paper that was previously dipped into acetone much like in a counterfeit pen the iodine causes a reaction when written on standard paper .

Comment: There is iodoform test... http://www.chemguide.co.uk/organicprops/carbonyls/iodoform.html

Comment: I doubt that much acetone would be left to detect unless the test were done soon after the dipping.

Comment: If the test was done soon after the dipping what would you test it with?

Comment: I would use my nose. I think humans can detect acetone at lower concentration and with more specificity than any simple chemical test. For detecting trace amounts I would use an extraction followed by gas chromatography and mass spectrometry.

Comment: As a couple comments and an answer imply, acetone is volatile enough that there would rapidly nothing left sufficient to analyze.  You would be better off testing for residual non-volatile components in the acetone.  Hopefully it was low grade ;)

Answer (score 3):

If significant amounts of acetone are left (according to my old lab manual, the analysis works with a 50 mg sample), you could use the reaction with 2-nitrobenzaldehyde in the presence of sodium hydroxide, which generates [indigo dye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigo_dye).

See also: [Baeyer–Drewson indigo synthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baeyer%E2%80%93Drewson_indigo_synthesis)